# how to download file in gae

Tags: java, google-app-engine, download, apache-poi

I am not sure if it can.
I want to parse an excel file and let user download it in my app(gae).

```
public class dumpDataServlet extends HttpServlet {  
    public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        String msg = "";
        boolean dumpFile = false;
        JSONObject json = null;
        resp.setCharacterEncoding(Constant.RESPONSE_CHARACTER_ENCODING);
        try {
            try {
                msg = req.getParameter("dumpFile") + " ";
                dumpFile = Boolean.valueOf(req.getParameter("dumpFile"));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }json = getFromOtherGAE();
            if (dumpFile) {
                OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
                this.parseExcelFile(json).write(out); //parseExcelFile will return a HSSFWorkbook
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } else {
                resp.getWriter().println(json.toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            msg = ex.getClass() + " " + ex.getMessage();
            resp.getWriter().println(msg);
        }
    }   
}
```

Is anything wrong in this code? Or gae just can't do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For the browser to recognize the output as Excel, you'll need to set some headers. Something like:

```
resp.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=download.xls");
```

Comment: i tried. but it still shows:{Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.}

Comment: Look in the log for a stack trace.

Comment: i tried. show nothing. i think that's because gae not allow it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you ever initialize your 'json' object. What happens when you run this code?